# non-singular divisors of the jacobian variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-curves, hodge-theory, jacobians

Let $X$ be a smooth, projective curve of genus at least $4$. The well-known divisor $\theta$ of the associated Jacobian variety is $\mathrm{Jac}(X)$ is singular and also ample. The $\theta$ divisor also has a very explicit desciption in terms of the Abel-Jacobi map. Of course, as $\theta$ is ample, a multiple of it is linearly equivalent to something smooth. I am looking for a non-singular divisor of $\mathrm{Jac}(X)$ with an "explicit" desciption. My main motivation is to find a non-singular divisor, so that I can compute the Hodge numbers of the divisor. I keep the question a little vague to encourage different answers. Any reference/hints will be most welcome.

Comment: For a complex curve, do you know how to construct immersion or embedding into $\Bbb{P}^n$ given by homogeneous polynomials in theta functions of the lattice ? (I don't) The zero of one of them will be ample or very ample

Comment: A general element of $|2\theta|$ is smooth, and it is fairly easy to compute its Hodge numbers via the standard exact sequence. I don't understand what else you might want.

Comment: @abx Could you suggest some reference or hints on the exact sequence you mention.

Comment: For $D$ a smooth divisor in a variety $X$, use the exact sequence $0\rightarrow \mathscr{O}_D(-D)\rightarrow \Omega ^1_{X|D}\rightarrow \Omega ^1_D\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @abx I am not an expert on abelian varieties. Could you please suggest some reference for the proof that $2\theta$ is very ample (or a general member of the associated linear system is smooth). I would like to understand the general member of the linear system, but I cannot find a good reference.

Comment: $|2\theta|$ is not very ample, but base-point free. You'll find this in any book on abelian varieties, e.g. Mumford or Birkenhake-Lange.